# Mariadb configuration is not loaded from my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

My mariadb configuration in my.cnf is not getting loaded for `"log-error"` and `"pid-file"`. I have checked other configurations params are loaded.

```
[root@kvm10 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
!includedir /etc/mysqld/conf.d
datadir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql_tmp
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
### TRT-3229 #####
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa = 1
myisam_repair_threads = 2
myisam_recover_options = FORCE
###################
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache=256
max_heap_table_size=256M
### TRT-4685 ###
max_connections=500
################
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[root@kvm10 ~]#
```

But the configuration value for `log-error` & `pid-file` is not picked by MariaDB.

```
[root@kvm10 ~]# mysql -e "show variables like 'pid_file'"
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                             |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| pid_file      | /mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql/kvm10.pid |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
[root@kvm10 ~]# mysql -e "show variables like 'log_error'"
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_error     |       |
+---------------+-------+
[root@kvm10 ~]#
```

Am I missing somethig or making some mistake. I have checked the files permissions in `/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log` & `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question on dba.stackexchange.com sister site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options from the config file should be picked up if you start the server by running `mysqld_safe`, either directly or via the old-style init script (MariaDB 5.5/10.0 or older Linux distributions). If you have MariaDB 10.1+ and Linux distributions with `systemd` support and start MariaDB server via the service, `mysqld_safe` is not used.

Another reason why they might not work is if you start `mysqld_safe` without `--defaults-file` option, and there is another config file somewhere else in default locations which overrides these options.

1) Add the options to `[mysqld]` section of the config file, restart the server and see if it helps.

If it doesn't help,

2a) if you run MariaDB server via `systemd` service, check the service configuration, maybe there is something in there;

2b) if you run MariaDB server via `mysqld_safe`, try to start it with `--defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf`, to make sure that this, only only this config file is used.